# Message Errors in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, messagebox

**I know & always use the:**

```
Try
Catch Ex As Exception("Error!")
End Try
```

I am just wondering, is there any other way in this simple format that is just as effective in making a message box error?

Bear in mind I use this in my VB.NET code behind my Asp.Net , so C# etc is out the question.

Is this the only solution for VB?

Comment: @Kallumasaurus..do you mean additional things  for exception handling apart from showing error message?

Comment: That syntax does not compile. Do you have `Option Strict` turned off? Also, where do you use Try/Catch? If you use it everywhere, then you're using it wrong. See "[Handling exceptions, is this a good way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469822/handling-exceptions-is-this-a-good-way)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to any other additional things apart from just showing **'Error!**' message.

You can further show the message description to the user by using `Ex.Message` or you can also  show `stack trace` which has caused the error

Hope this helps you..

Comment: This does help indeed , thank you Avinash it has been bugging me for sometime this morning and I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(btnsave, btnsave.GetType(), "message", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", True)
```

this code will be executed as client script..!