# Updating disconnected Object graph

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a entity with nested collections as follows

```
public class Profile
{
    [Required]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; }
}

public class Plugin
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Counter> Counters{ get; set; }
}

public class Counter
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeVal { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to develop a routine (that when given a list of Profiles) Inserts/Updates/Deletes the entire nested object Graph

I.e Basically i want to do delete update and insert, Profiles, Plugins and Counters where applicable in the simplest and most efficient way i can

Given a new disconnected List of Profiles (NewProfiles) and a ClientId

```
using (var dc = new JCEContext())
{

    var existingProfiles = dc.Profiles.AsNoTracking().Where(x => Id == ClientId).ToList();
    var addedProfiles = NewProfiles.Except(existingProfiles, x => x.Id).ToList();
    var deletedTeachers = existingProfiles.Except(Profiles, x => x.Id);
    var modifiedProfiles = dcmProfiles.Except(addedProfiles, x => x.Id);

    addedProfiles.ToList().ForEach(tchr => dc.Entry(tchr).State = EntityState.Added);
    deletedTeachers.ToList().ForEach(tchr => dc.Entry(tchr).State = EntityState.Deleted);

    foreach (var profile in modifiedProfiles)
    {

        var entity = dc.Profiles.Find(profile.Id);

        if (entity == null)
            continue;

        var entry = dc.Entry(entity);

        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(profile);

    }
    dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

Helper function

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other,Func<T, TKey> getKey)
{
    return from item in items
           join otherItem in other on getKey(item)
           equals getKey(otherItem) into tempItems
           from temp in tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where ReferenceEquals(null, temp) || temp.Equals(default(T))
           select item;
}
```

The above routines will only update the top level objects

How would i go about applying the logic i have here, to the rest of the object graph? i.e insert update and delete plugins as well as their associated counters?

**Note** : the majority of this code was an example found somewhere on the internet I've adapted

Comment: GraphDiff is the tool for this.

Comment: I have looked at that, however i couldn't quite figure out how to get it to work, there isn't a lot of documentation for people starting from ground zero, Is it possible for you to post an answer with some sample code that's in the ball part of what i need?

Comment: I've seen sample code here at StackOverflow, try "site:stackoverflow.com GraphDiff" in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to solve the problem with [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff), Complete solution below. I'm open to someone posting a more elegant solution.

```
public Boolean SubmitProfiles(String dcmClientId, List<DcmProfile> dcmProfiles)
{

    try
    {

        using (var dc = new JCEContext())
        {
            var existing = dc.DcmProfiles.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.DcmClientId == dcmClientId).ToList();
            var added = dcmProfiles.Except(existing, x => x.Id).ToList();
            var deleted = existing.Except(dcmProfiles, x => x.Id).ToList();
            var modified = dcmProfiles.Except(added, x => x.Id);

            // Update modified profiles
            foreach (var dcmProfile in modified)
                dc.UpdateGraph(dcmProfile, map => map
                    .OwnedCollection(profile => profile.Plugins, with => with
                        .OwnedCollection(plugin => plugin.Counters)));

            // Add new profiles
            added.ForEach(profile => dc.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Added);

            // Delete nonexistent profiles
            deleted.ForEach(profile => dc.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Deleted);

            dc.SaveChanges();

        }

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```

The below is an extension method that compare values from two lists and return entities from one which are not present in the other.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKey)
{
    return from item in items
            join otherItem in other on getKey(item)
            equals getKey(otherItem) into tempItems
            from temp in tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ReferenceEquals(null, temp) || temp.Equals(default(T))
            select item;

}
```

Comment: Be careful not to pick up bad habits from the Internet. `try{}catch(Exception ex){Log(ex); return false;}` will continue execution of your program no matter what horrible thing just happened and regardless of the state of your program. It also logs only the stack trace _up to_ the `catch` block - you will not know who _called_ the method in question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, in this case its a webservice call and only needs to return a result, and nothing about an exception. However i have been wrestling with what is the best exception handling patterns at any given level in an application architecture. I think i really need to do more research into this

Comment: See [A: Handling Exceptions, is this a good way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469822/handling-exceptions-is-this-a-good-way/2469864#2469864).

Answer (score 1):

Some more from the internet: [Reattaching Entity Graphs with the Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33088/Reattaching-Entity-Graphs-with-the-Entity-Framewor) or [DbContext Merge for detached Entities](http://blog.technophobie.de/2012/05/dbcontext-merge-fur-detached-entitaten.html) (German).

Basic idea behind both links is to use expressions to define the paths you want to include into the update.

If you do not want to define these paths then you i would suggest to use a common baseclass or interface for your pocos.
Then use something like this (untested):

```
    public static void MergeObject<T>(this DataContext dc, T modifiedItem)
    {
        MergeObjectGraph<T>(dc, new List<T>() { modifiedItem });
    }

    public static void MergeObjectGraph<T>(this DataContext dc, IEnumerable<T> modifiedCollection)
    {
        var existingItems = dc.Set<T>.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        var addedItems = modifiedCollection.Except(existingItems, x => x.Id).ToList();
        var deletedItems = existingItems.Except(modifiedCollection, x => x.Id);

        addedItems.ToList().ForEach(tchr => dc.Entry(tchr).State = EntityState.Added);
        deletedItems.ToList().ForEach(tchr => dc.Entry(tchr).State = EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var item in modifiedCollection)
        {
            var navigationProperties = profile.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(YourBaseType)).ToList();
            var nestedCollections = profile.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsGenereicType && p.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

            foreach (var navProp in navigationProperties)
            {
                var p = navProp.GetValue(item,null);
                dc.MergeObject(navProp); //need to call this by reflection
            }

            foreach (var nested in nestedCollections)
            {
                var coll = nested.GetValue(item,null);
                dc.MergeObjectGraph(coll); //need to call this by reflection
            }
            var entity = dc.Set<T>.Find(item.Id);

            if (entity == null)
                continue;

            var entry = dc.Entry(entity);

            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
        }
    }
```

Problems here: Performance of deeply nested graphs, possibly touching items you don't want to touch and circular reference.

Comment: Great answer, i also like what you did with the code, ill work through the articles tomorrow and mark accordingly, thanks