# Whats the best way to handle errors in code?

Tags: c#, exception

So I'm a little concerned about my error handling... Currently my execution path looks something like this:

> Users.aspx -> App_Code/User.cs -> Data Layer/User.cs

So now when I try to update a user record, I put my Try/Catch block in the event handler and ensure that only the App_Code class interacts with the data layer. Exceptions that happen on the data layer, to my understanding, should bubble up to the event handler below.

In the data layer, I started off with this:

```
public void Update()
{
    var product = (from p in db.products
                        where p.productid == id
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();

    if (product != null)
    {
        // update the thing
    }
}
```

More info [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/24vc0r/i_think_ive_been_writing_bugs_into_my_code_here/).

After chatting with a friend, he recommended something like this:

```
public void Update()
{
    int count = db.users.Count(u => u.userid == id);

    if (count == 0) // no user found
    {
        throw new ValidationException(String.Format("User not found for id {0}.", id));
    }
    if (count > 1) // multiple users
    {
        throw new ValidationException(String.Format("Multiple users found for id {0}.", id));
    }

    var user = db.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userid == id);
    // update the user record
}
```

Then I went onto IRC where they suggested I [create my own Exceptions](https://gist.github.com/hagbarddenstore/d25dc2e6bf66bdcd7bea).

I can see the pros here, but it seems a bit unnecessary when my friend's option will work just fine.

Basically I'm just really confused as to how I should handle this... Obviously my initial option is insufficient, but it seems like creating my own exceptions might be complicating things too much.

So what should I do here?

Comment: This question is really too broad for [so]. You might have better luck on [programmers.se]. In the meantime, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469822/handling-exceptions-is-this-a-good-way and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210900/how-to-implement-error-handling.

Comment: Don't check the database by counting the available UserIDs. That is inefficient and also a race condition. Instead handle the result of the update, so if it returns 0 no row was updated what is an error. To avoid that multiple UdserIDs are in the database use an unique index.

Comment: If you are the only person whole will read those exceptions (or error reports containing those), then throw what you want - because you hopefully will still remember why and where your code throws a particulate exception. However, if there is the slightest chance that other people/developers will encounter those exceptions, then do not repurpose existing exceptions but rather create your own - otherwise confusion and misunderstandings a prone to happen during debugging/reading error logs...

Comment: Rather use .Single() and let the exception propagate upwards from the DAL layer. You are expecting to find exactly one product from your database with any given id.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the *other* side here. As in, who is consuming that API. Whoever calls that method, they probably want to know *that* something went wrong. Exceptions provide that (return values could, too), while your initial approach doesn't.

Now consider that the consumer might want to distringuish the two cases »no users found« and »multiple users found«. In that case they're out of luck because you throw the same exception for both and have no way of distinguishing the two cases¹. In this case having distinct exception types for the different things that could have gone wrong can help.

But *only* if you actually need that capability in the caller. If you're using that method yourself, it's not part of a public API where you don't know how it might be used, and whether distinguishing those cases would be useful, I'd say don't bother.

I've used my own exception types rarely so far, and mostly when writing parsers for something where the exception type could hint at what exactly went wrong and you could use additional properties of the exception to generate a useful error message. In most other code I don't think I've ever done that.

---

¹ You *could* compare the exception message, but I'd advise never to do that. The message is for a user or developer to read. It could be translated into other languages (e.g. all exceptions from .NET are in your UI language, usually) which makes such an approach *very* brittle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. It really helps :) In my friend's suggestion there (throwing the ValidationExceptions), the error message I specify does distinguish between two cases... Doesn't it?

Comment: It does for a human, but not for the code. As I mentioned in my footnote, you *could* distinguish them in code as well, but you should not.