# XDocument.Save(string) Error Handling

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

What are the best practices for handling exceptions that may be thrown during execution of `XDocument.Save(string)`?

I see that `XmlExceptions` can be thrown - should I also check for `IOExceptions`?

This is for a high availability application and I'd like to watch for and trap errors related to disc space. Should I be doing multiple catches for `IOException` and `XMLException`? What does Stack Overflow recommend?

Comment: Is there a difference in how you would handle `XmlException` vs. `IoException` vs. any other exception?  Or would logic be the same?

Comment: Why catch _any_ exceptions? Are you going to actually _handle_ them? Will you make it like they didn't happen? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469822/handling-exceptions-is-this-a-good-way/2469864.

Comment: The exceptions will be caught and either handled appropriately. In the case of being out of disc space I'd be writing to the other disc that is on the server instead and setting a timer to try again in a few hours. I work for a hospital system and generally speaking someone will notice the disc being out of space and we'll have the SAN team allocate additional space. In the mean time I'd like to buffer to a non-volatile location.

Comment: @user1693074 As others already answered, figuring out all possible exceptions is daunting, and largely unnecessary if they're all to be handled the same.  Sounds like what you want is simply `catch(Exception e)` and in this handler execute your plan B, and really no need for distinction of exception type.  If you want to later understand why plan B was invoked, then simply also log the exception which will give you type, message and whole 9 yards of it.

Comment: Frankly, you'd be better to have a monitoring tool monitor for out of disk space, rather than have code deal with it. If this is a high-availability application, then I'd put try/catch blocks at the outermost level, to run a reliable retry operation - after logging the full exception (ex.ToString()). There's no way it makes sense to catch such exceptions in every method. Instead, catch them as late as possible (like, where they would crash the app if you didn't catch them, or where they have to be in order to do the retry logic).

Comment: @JohnSaunders We do have a few tools that do monitoring. The problem, as with all things IT, is that even being staffed 24/7 in our monitoring center there is still a delay from when the alert goes out until disc space is made available.

This application will run, periodically, 24/7/365 and it will be pulling files from an offsite/vendor location into our system. If we run out of room no one is likely to stop the program and thus the program NEEDS to be able to handle those kinds of problems.

I don't mean to suggest trapping every single possible error, just the ones I truly care about.

Comment: Care about, and can _do_ something about. That's the combination.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Since `IOException` and `XmlException` mean two totally different things, I would deal with them seperatly, **as long as you are doing something other then logging and notifying the user**.

By other I mean, for example, catching an `IOException` and trying to write to a different location, like a backup receiver. For `XMLException`, triggering off a notification to the XML Supplier that their XML is invalid.

If all you need is to log and ignore, there is no need for catching them seperatly. If no logging is done, just let it go up the call chain.

Comment: I suggest you inform the OP what you mean by "doing something other", as most developers will read that and do try/catch/log/ignore.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a daunting task. Consider the code flow you're executing:

```
public void Save(string fileName, SaveOptions options)
{
  XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = XNode.GetXmlWriterSettings(options);
  if (this.declaration != null)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.declaration.Encoding))
    {
      try
      {
        xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(this.declaration.Encoding);
      }
      catch (ArgumentException ex)
      {
      }
    }
  }
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xmlWriterSettings))
    this.Save(writer);
}
```

Within that, `XmlWriter.Create(fileName, xmlWriterSettings)` **alone** can throw the following exceptions:

- ArgumentNullException
- ArgumentOutOfRangeException
- ArgumentException
- NotSupportedException
- IOException

for an enumerable number of reasons. Further, this code (which throws those exceptions explicitly):

```
private unsafe void Init(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, int rights, bool useRights, FileShare share, int bufferSize, FileOptions options, Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, string msgPath, bool bFromProxy, bool useLongPath, bool checkHost)
{
  if (path == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("path", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Path"));
  if (path.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
  FileSystemRights fileSystemRights = (FileSystemRights) rights;
  this._fileName = msgPath;
  this._exposedHandle = false;
  FileShare fileShare = share & ~FileShare.Inheritable;
  string paramName = (string) null;
  if (mode < FileMode.CreateNew || mode > FileMode.Append)
    paramName = "mode";
  else if (!useRights && (access < FileAccess.Read || access > FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    paramName = "access";
  else if (useRights && (fileSystemRights < FileSystemRights.ReadData || fileSystemRights > FileSystemRights.FullControl))
    paramName = "rights";
  else if (fileShare < FileShare.None || fileShare > (FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete))
    paramName = "share";
  if (paramName != null)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Enum"));
  if (options != FileOptions.None && (options & (FileOptions) 67092479) != FileOptions.None)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("options", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Enum"));
  if (bufferSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedPosNum"));
  if ((!useRights && (access & FileAccess.Write) == (FileAccess) 0 || useRights && (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Write) == (FileSystemRights) 0) && (mode == FileMode.Truncate || mode == FileMode.CreateNew || (mode == FileMode.Create || mode == FileMode.Append)))
  {
    if (!useRights)
      throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidFileMode&AccessCombo", (object) mode, (object) access));
    else
      throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidFileMode&RightsCombo", (object) mode, (object) fileSystemRights));
  }
  else
  {
    if (useRights && mode == FileMode.Truncate)
    {
      if (fileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.Write)
      {
        useRights = false;
        access = FileAccess.Write;
      }
      else
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidFileModeTruncate&RightsCombo", (object) mode, (object) fileSystemRights));
    }
    int dwDesiredAccess = useRights ? rights : (access == FileAccess.Read ? int.MinValue : (access == FileAccess.Write ? 1073741824 : -1073741824));
    int maxPathLength = useLongPath ? Path.MaxLongPath : Path.MaxPath;
    string path1 = Path.NormalizePath(path, true, maxPathLength);
    this._fileName = path1;
    if (path1.StartsWith("\\\\.\\", StringComparison.Ordinal))
      throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_DevicesNotSupported"));
    Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(path1, true);
    if (path1.IndexOf(':', 2) != -1)
      throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_PathFormatNotSupported"));
    bool flag1 = false;
    if (!useRights && (access & FileAccess.Read) != (FileAccess) 0 || useRights && (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) != (FileSystemRights) 0)
    {
      if (mode == FileMode.Append)
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidAppendMode"));
      flag1 = true;
    }
    if (!CodeAccessSecurityEngine.QuickCheckForAllDemands())
    {
      FileIOPermissionAccess access1 = FileIOPermissionAccess.NoAccess;
      if (flag1)
        access1 |= FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
      if (!useRights && (access & FileAccess.Write) != (FileAccess) 0 || useRights && (fileSystemRights & (FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles | FileSystemRights.Delete | FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions | FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership)) != (FileSystemRights) 0 || useRights && (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Synchronize) != (FileSystemRights) 0 && mode == FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
      {
        if (mode == FileMode.Append)
          access1 |= FileIOPermissionAccess.Append;
        else
          access1 |= FileIOPermissionAccess.Write;
      }
      AccessControlActions control = secAttrs != null && (IntPtr) secAttrs.pSecurityDescriptor != IntPtr.Zero ? AccessControlActions.Change : AccessControlActions.None;
      new FileIOPermission(access1, control, new string[1]
      {
        path1
      }, 0 != 0, 0 != 0).Demand();
    }
    share &= ~FileShare.Inheritable;
    bool flag2 = mode == FileMode.Append;
    if (mode == FileMode.Append)
      mode = FileMode.OpenOrCreate;
    if (FileStream._canUseAsync && (options & FileOptions.Asynchronous) != FileOptions.None)
      this._isAsync = true;
    else
      options &= ~FileOptions.Asynchronous;
    int dwFlagsAndAttributes = (int) (options | (FileOptions) 1048576);
    int newMode = Win32Native.SetErrorMode(1);
    try
    {
      string str = path1;
      if (useLongPath)
        str = Path.AddLongPathPrefix(str);
      this._handle = Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(str, dwDesiredAccess, share, secAttrs, mode, dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr.Zero);
      if (this._handle.IsInvalid)
      {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (errorCode == 3 && path1.Equals(Directory.InternalGetDirectoryRoot(path1)))
          errorCode = 5;
        bool flag3 = false;
        if (!bFromProxy)
        {
          try
          {
            new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, new string[1]
            {
              this._fileName
            }, 0 != 0, 0 != 0).Demand();
            flag3 = true;
          }
          catch (SecurityException ex)
          {
          }
        }
        if (flag3)
          __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, this._fileName);
        else
          __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, msgPath);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      Win32Native.SetErrorMode(newMode);
    }
    if (Win32Native.GetFileType(this._handle) != 1)
    {
      this._handle.Close();
      throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_FileStreamOnNonFiles"));
    }
    else
    {
      if (this._isAsync)
      {
        bool flag3 = false;
        new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Assert();
        try
        {
          flag3 = ThreadPool.BindHandle((SafeHandle) this._handle);
        }
        finally
        {
          CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
          if (!flag3)
            this._handle.Close();
        }
        if (!flag3)
          throw new IOException(Environment.GetResourceString("IO.IO_BindHandleFailed"));
      }
      if (!useRights)
      {
        this._canRead = (access & FileAccess.Read) != (FileAccess) 0;
        this._canWrite = (access & FileAccess.Write) != (FileAccess) 0;
      }
      else
      {
        this._canRead = (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadData) != (FileSystemRights) 0;
        this._canWrite = (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) != (FileSystemRights) 0 || (fileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.AppendData) != (FileSystemRights) 0;
      }
      this._canSeek = true;
      this._isPipe = false;
      this._pos = 0L;
      this._bufferSize = bufferSize;
      this._readPos = 0;
      this._readLen = 0;
      this._writePos = 0;
      if (flag2)
        this._appendStart = this.SeekCore(0L, SeekOrigin.End);
      else
        this._appendStart = -1L;
    }
  }
}
```

Uses a significant number of dependencies which can throw their own exceptions.

My advice, first make sure you **really** need to know every possible exception that can be thrown. As stated in John and I's conversation, **in the 99%+ case it doesn't matter what exception is thrown it can be handled the same way.**

For more information surrounding **when** you might *actually* need to know all of the exception types, please read through the comments.

Finally, *if you do* need to know every exception, get a copy of JetBrains dotPeek and work through the .NET Framework code.

Comment: is that really your advice? Or should the OP simply not try to catch all exceptions? It seems to me that the OP is inexperienced and still thinks that all exceptions should be caught.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: my advice is to yes, work through the code. For example, to ensure a durable high availability solution to the XML file, I would be interested in `IOException` and not some of the others. Around here, if that exception is thrown there is a completely different code flow. Further, a security exception being thrown, that's also another code flow. Tickets have to be opened with different teams and workflows worked in different ways.

Comment: @Yet, surely the ticket would be opened based on the exception type? That is, ex.GetType(), and not based on an enumeration of all possible exceptions thrown. The list of possible exceptions is an implementation dependency that Microsoft is free to change at any time.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, because of our availability we do in fact run workflows based on the exception types. When you need to run 24/7/365; entire teams need notified and paged immediately at times. And as for the implementation detail changing, of course, they could change it at any time; but that's not how it generally works in practice. I mean, they are consistent with the types of exceptions they throw and have been for years.

Comment: So I guess I'm not seeing why "`catch (Exception ex){DispatchException(ex);}`" wouldn't work.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, that may work, but eventually the type of exception has to be known. Further, every piece of the code doesn't need to run with the availability; more often it's some very critical piece. The workflow will often involve loading messages onto MQ's, creating tickets, paging teams, and more. When waking teams up in the middle of the night you have to provide very specific information as to what workflow, when, where, and how exactly it failed as 7+ teams may be involved and a cascade of pagers set off. Deferring it to a method for execution doesn't change that I need to know.

Comment: `ex.GetType()`... Ok, I haven't seen your code. I've just seen some really bad code that tries to catch all exceptions. The more "high-availability", the worse.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I have to totally agree that in the 90%+, nay maybe 99%+, case I don't care what the exception is. No matter what it is, my outcome is the same. I stop the workflow in some standard way and move on.

Comment: I'd feel _so_ much better if you were to make that point in the answer. Your answer may be read by many as saying "go find out all the possible exceptions and catch them all".

Comment: To be clear you're suggesting the use of the IOException and/or XMLException classes to trap the critical errors I need and then use the general Exception class to trap/handle the other things (handle meaning, for the general stuff, to retry/log/etc)?

Can I use the general Exception class to handle out of disc space or would IOException be the best practice?