# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

I have two gridviews in asp.net separated using Ajax's tab container. In one button click event, I want the two gridviews to be populated using a datasource from two different stored procedures.

First gridview - detailed summary of sales per tenant

Second gridview - Consolidated sales group per date

**Here's the code**

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDSRDetailed", con);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", txtdatefrom.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", txtdateto.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", hdnLoc.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RP", hdnRP.Value);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            grdDailySalesReport.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdDailySalesReport.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdDailySalesReport.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

This code works only with one gridview, I know it is possible to do this using SQLDatasource, But that method is not my option because I have used a complex SQL queries and not ideal to do it using SQLDATASOURCE.SELECTCOMMAND.

I tried this and it gives me this error

***There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.***

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spDSRDetailed", con);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("spDSRConso", con);
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", txtdatefrom.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", txtdateto.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", hdnLoc.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RP", hdnRP.Value);

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", txtdatefrom.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", txtdateto.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", hdnLoc.Value);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RP", hdnRP.Value);


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            grdDailySalesReport.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdDailySalesReport.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdDailySalesReport.DataBind();


            grdDSRConso.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            grdDSRConso.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            grdDSRConso.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi @John, is it okay to change the title of my question to: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. (the actual error)

Comment: Sure, but the "in ASP.NET C#" part should be left out. It's not even relevant.

Comment: I see, I just thought that part is needed to isolate the error to asp.net c# only, Thanks a lot @John :)

Comment: But what makes you think the error is specific to ASP.NET C#? Maybe it would also happen for ASP.NET VB? Maybe not specific to ASP.NET at all?

Comment: Also, please learn about `using` blocks, and don't do `try {/* code */} catch (Exception ex){throw ex;}`. It's better to just do `/* code */`

Comment: Since college days, I learned and was asked to always use try catch in my codes to avoid the system in crashing. Is using the "using" block has the same effects with try catch?

Comment: Your college instructors lied to you about try/catch. It should be used rarely, and your code does nothing except make it difficult to ever learn where the real exception came from.

Comment: ok. I'll take that, but how about when the system crashes? the try catch function works well with that.

Comment: try/catch is too often used to _hide_ exceptions. Instead, let them propagate to the outermost layer of the application, log them, _and then let the application crash_. Crashing means you made a mistake. Logging the exception allows you to fix the mistake. Hiding exceptions prevents you from fixing your errors, but you **still** made the mistake, and catching the exception will not fix it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/throwing-exceptions-best-practices, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881473/why-catch-and-rethrow-an-exception-in-c, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469822/handling-exceptions-is-this-a-good-way.

Comment: Ok! I got the point, so you are saying that it is okay for the web-based application to crash, for the purpose of getting the correct error for it to be fixed. However as a user of the system, it is better to see something like a page or a message box rather than a lines of codes

Comment: Thanks for the references. highly appreciated

Comment: There is a `customErrors` section in the web.config file which will allow a pretty error page to be used. Don't worry so much about how it looks when the application fails - instead worry about fixing the application and doing what you can to make sure the problem doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: yeah, I know about customErrors, thanks a lot!! Big help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` and the message said :

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first

So you need to close the first `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` first.

Try this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
grdDailySalesReport.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
grdDailySalesReport.DataSource = reader;
grdDailySalesReport.DataBind();

reader.Close();

reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
grdDSRConso.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
grdDSRConso.DataSource = reader;
grdDSRConso.DataBind();

reader.Close();
```

Comment: Better still, the `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`s and `SqlConnection` all need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Hi @Iswanto, thanks it worked! thanks a lot. Do you think I used the best method in terms of performance / speed or are there any alternatives to meet what I want?

Comment: Anyway I'll accept your answer, but if there's someone who can do the alternative to say it is better in terms of speed I will accept that :) thanks a lot @Iswanto for help. God bless you

Comment: @rickyProgrammer to get the best performance you want to use `using` blocks for all `SqlConnections` and make them as small as possible. .NET uses [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so when you exit the using block it does not actually close the connection but instead return it to the pool. This lets some other part of the code re-use the connection an not have the overhead of initiating the connection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: more importantly, a `using` block ensures that the object in it _will_ get cleaned up in a timely manner, even if an exception is thrown. It should be used for all objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface, in this case, the `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`s and `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Thank you both for your wisdom and advices :) very much appreciated